# WEB API 2 custom IAuthenticationFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I'm sorry, I'm new in WEB API 2, maybe my question was asked but I can't find anywhere.
In web api 2 we can use IAuthenticationFilter to implement custom authentication, everything is clear with AuthenticateAsync but I have problem with ChallengeAsync
as it called for each request no matter is authentication succeeded or not.
In https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters this topic there written that I should create ResponseMessage by means of HttpActionResult.ExecuteAsync and if HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized I should add response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate otherwise only create HttpResponseMessage response, in my case when authentication is succeeded I need to return IHttpActionResult from Controller.action with data , in this case what I need to do use response which was created by ChallengeAsync or create another one.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this, and I'm seeing the same behavior and was just about to post the same question!